# PHP static/abstract: How to access a private variable with inherited method?

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a basic abstract class (BC).

I have an abstract class X that extends BC. X has some private variables.

I search for a possibility to use a method, defined in BC (and therefor inherited into X) that can list ALL variables of X, including the private ones.

As far as I understand, that is impossible unless I transfer the methods from BC into a trait using this trait in the BC and X class definition?

Is there any other solution that allows me to have the methods defined in BC directly?

Comment: Private members are called private because they are private.

Comment: I have no clue how you just went from `private` members to `Trait`s.

Comment: `Protected` is good in this case

Comment: can you not use protected instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing through the call to your method to X, if BC is an instance of X. Method in X again will deliver the required information.

```
if ($this instanceof X) {
    ... // call X-specific method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstanding on my side - sorry, still an OO beginner (and suffering).

I was not aware that private means REALLY private to a class and that this is not even inherited to inherited classes.

But it makes sense. My conclusion: Use private only VERY rarely, standard usage would be rather protected than private (for everything that shall be inherited but non-accessible from outside).